# RandomAccessFile Endianness issue

Tags: java, stream, endianness, randomaccessfile

I have to read data from a binary file in byte, int and long data sizes. I read it with `RandomAccessFile`'s methods `readInt`, `readLong`, `readByte`. The problem is that the endiannes of the system 
(Windows 8.1) and the endiannes of the file are different. For example this number  [image] in the file is actually the number `2`, but it is read from the system as `33554432`.

How can I fix this problem and be able to read data chunks with  `RandomAccessFile`'s methods ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> the problem is that the endianness of the system ... and the endianness of the file are different.

No. They are the same. Look at the data. The least significant byte is at the start. That is little-endian, which is the Intel endianness. (**Not** the 'Windows endianness', which AFAIK doesn't exist except w.r.t. a specific platform).

The problem is that the endianness-ness of the file and the system are little-endian, but `RandomAccessFile` is big-endian.

The way to address this in Java is via NIO and `ByteBuffer`, using native byte order instead of the default.

Comment: Would you wrap each byte-array from RandomAccessFile with ByteBuffer, and then reorder it?

Comment: I still find the names confusing: little-endian means that little is at the end... oh no, at the start.